# The permissions granted to user 'suresh\admin' are insufficient for performing this operation

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

My report was build and deployed successfully but after I give the url `http://localhost/ReportServer` it returns

> The permissions granted to user 'suresh\admin' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied).

Can you help me ?

Comment: Please elaborate some more: Which system are you using?

Comment: Please do not put [tags into the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/173356)

Answer (score 0):

Based on MSDN :

> Permission to access report server content and operations are granted
>   through role assignments. On a new installation, only local
>   administrators have access to a report server. To grant access to
>   other users, a local administrator must create a role assignment that
>   specifies a domain user or group account, one or more roles that
>   define the tasks the user can perform, and a scope (usually the Home
>   folder or root node of the report server folder hierarchy). You can
>   use Report Manager to create the role assignments. For more
>   information, search for "Role Assignments" in SQL Server Books Online.